# Encountering Authorization Error on HTTP POST Request in Browser, but Works Perfectly on Postman

Tags: php, reactjs, post, authorization, amazon-ecs

I'm currently experiencing an issue with a POST request. I have an authorization header with basic username and password authentication. Interestingly, when I tried the same request  using Postman, it worked perfectly. However, when I attempted to make the same call using fetch, I encountered an error 401. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Here is the postman auth header (work's fine):
[image]

Here is the fetch call (used with same Authorization header:

```
const authHeader = {"Authorization": "Basic **********************"}

fetch(`${url}`, {
          method,
          body,
          headers:authHeader
        }).then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
```

I don't know if this is related to the issue, but it wouldn't hurt to add information to find a solution... The API is written in PHP and hosted on AWS ECS. Could the problem possibly be caused by PHP or AWS?

Answer (score 2):

This code will works.

```
fetch(`${url}`, {
    method: method,
    headers: authHeader,
    body: body
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((body) => {
        console.log(body)
    })
```

Demo with Spotify get token POST call using fetch.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
const method = 'POST'
const authHeader = { "Authorization": "Basic <your base64>" }
const body = new URLSearchParams({
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
})

fetch(`${url}`, {
    method: method,
    headers: authHeader,
    body: body
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((body) => {
        console.log(body)
    })
```

Result
[image]

OR Version 2 with using username/password instead of `<base64>`

```
const base64 = Buffer.from('<username>' + ":" + '<password>').toString('base64')
const authHeader = { "Authorization": `Basic ${base64}` }
```

instead of

```
const authHeader = { "Authorization": "Basic <your base64>" }
```

Screen capture for username/password from VS code

[image]

Screen capture for username/password from `Postman`

[image]

#### Alterative method using `axios`

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const base64 = require('base-64');

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const URL='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
        const client_id = '<your username>'    // OR username
        const client_secret = '<your password>'    // OR password
        const response = await axios.post(URL,
            new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            }),
            {
                headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

getToken()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that's exactly what I've already done, that's why I'm pulling my hair out and don't understand what's not working.
I've checked the DevTools in Chrome and confirmed that all the data is being transmitted correctly, and the authorization appears to be identical to what I used in Postman.

Comment: @DavidSachakov, I updated my answer, you can using `axios` instead of `fetch` method.

Comment: @DavidSachakov, I tested fetch POST call from index.html. It works fine. Can you try my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738328/how-do-i-fetch-from-a-page-i-postedexpress-backend-and-html-frontend/75740070#75740070)? No BASIC Auth but you can modify from that code.