# How do I fetch from a page I posted(express backend and html frontend)

Tags: javascript, html, express, frontend, backend

I have a login page as index.html, it asks for email and password, and has a submit button like this:

`<input type="submit" value="Log In" id="loginbutton">`

Then in my app.js I have:

```
app.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
    // check if the user is in the list of registered users
    const user = users.find((c) => c.user == req.body.email)

    // if user dose not exist, send the user to the register page
    if(user == null) {
        res.json({nouser: true, wrongpassword: false, username: "null", accessToken: "null", refreshToken: "null"})
    }else if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        const accessToken = generateAccessToken({user: req.body.email})
        const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken({user: req.body.email})

        res.json({nouser: false, wrongpassword: false, username: user.username, accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken})
    }else {
        res.json({nouser: false, wrongpassword: true,  username: "null", accessToken: "null", refreshToken: "null"})
    }
})
```

So now when I click on the log in(submit) button I could get to the page of localhost:4000/login with a json in it. However, I don't want that. I tried to parse that json in my index.html with fetch so that I could decide whether to have an alert or redirect people to the user page or register page, etc. like this:

```
function main() {
     let url = "http://localhost:4000/login";
     fetch(url, {method: "GET"})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {processObject(json)})
}

function processObject({nouser, wrongpassword, username, accessToken, refreshToken}) {
      if(nouser) {
          displayConfirm()
      }else if(wrongpassword) {
          wrongPswdAlert()
      }
}
```

However it doesn't stay on index.html to show alert or redirect it to somewhere else like I want it to do. I wonder how could I change my code for it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it.

I removed `bcrypt` hash password comparison to simplify.

`Users` is  the `hard-code` array in `server.js`

And to mimic for `displayConfirm()` and `wrongPswdAlert()` by `alert` dialog with parameter.

#### Backend side

#1 The `server.js` with `express`

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
app.use(cors())

// for form-data of Body
const forms = multer();
app.use(forms.array());

// for x-www-form-urlencoded of Body
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// for raw JSON of Body
app.use(express.json());

const users = [
    {
        'user': 'user1@test.com',
        'password': '1234'
    },
    {
        'user': 'user2@test.com',
        'password': 'abcd'
    }
]

function generateAccessToken(data) {
    return require('crypto').randomBytes(12).toString('hex')
}

function generateRefreshToken(data) {
    return require('crypto').randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
}
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = users.find((c) => c.user == req.body.email)
    if (user == null) {
        res.json({ nouser: true, wrongpassword: false, username: "null", accessToken: "null", refreshToken: "null" })
    } else if (req.body.password === user.password) {
        const accessToken = generateAccessToken({ user: req.body.email })
        const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken({ user: req.body.email })
        res.json({ nouser: false, wrongpassword: false, username: user.username, accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken, body_password: req.body.password, user_password: user.password })
    } else {
        res.json({ nouser: false, wrongpassword: true, username: "null", accessToken: "null", refreshToken: "null" })
    }
})

app.listen(4000, () => { console.log("Listening on : 4000") })
```

#2 Install dependencies

```
npm install express cors crypto multer
```

#3 Run it

```
node server.js
```

[image]

#### Frontend side

Save as `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Demo for login</h1>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="username">User Name:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="username"
        name="username"
        value="user1@test.com"
      /><br /><br />
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="password"
        name="password"
        value="1234"
      /><br /><br />
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="loginbutton" />

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function passJson(data) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
        if (data.nouser) {
          alert("no user : yes"); // displayConfirm()
        } else if (data.wrongpassword) {
          alert("wrong password : yes"); // wrongPswdAlert()
        }
      }
      async function main() {
        try {
          const url = "http://localhost:4000/login";
          const method = "POST";
          const authHeader = {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          };

          await fetch(`${url}`, {
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: document.getElementById("username").value,
              password: document.getElementById("password").value,
            }),
            headers: authHeader,
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((body) => {
              passJson(body);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Error: ${err}`;
        }
      }

      const button = document.getElementById("loginbutton");
      button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        main();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#2 Run it by VS code Extension - [`Live Server`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)
With `index.html`

[image]

#### Test with both running

#1 - registered user

[image]

#2 - unregistered user

[image]

#3 - wrong password
[image]

*Note - Frontend JSON display will be displayed after close the alert dialog.